# Custom view expose to PowerBI via OData

Tags: acumatica

I have created a custom SQL view and a customization to create a customize report. Now I have created a Generic Inquiry to expose it to PowerBI via OData.

I looks like because it is a customization, it is not appearing in PowerBI. Same works if I add only existing DAC. (see screenshot for more info).

Let me know if I am missing anything. Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Do not include an underscore in alias when you create GI to expose via OData.